# Swift/Cocoa json parse error?

Tags: json, xcode, swift

New to Swift/iphone dev ...

If I have a string in json that is an array of objs, it can start with a bracket '['.  According to the json spec, afaik, this is okay.  However, the following blows up as a unit test in swift/xcode:

```
var json = "[{\"class\":\"ProductDesign\"},{\"class\":\"ProductDesign\"}]"
let jsonObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

I've seen blog write-ups of people doing exactly this but it does not work for me (xcode does some funny stuff, popping up :

```
0x287784:  je     0x28778d                  ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 61
0x287786:  addl   $0x10, %esp
0x287789:  popl   %esi
0x28778a:  popl   %edi
0x28778b:  popl   %ebp
0x28778c:  retl   
0x28778d:  leal   0xea35(%esi), %eax
0x287793:  movl   0x468ef(%esi), %ecx
0x287799:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%ecx)
0x28779c:  movl   $0x0, 0xc(%ecx)
0x2877a3:  int3   
0x2877a4:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
```

Any ideas?  Bug in this release??  Programmer stupidity?

Comment: PLEASE go to json.org and spend the 5-10 minutes it takes to learn JSON.  Then you will be a bit more able to actually code what you understand, rather than blindly copying code you don't understand.

Comment: Wow, you sir, have just earned the reputation imo as a jerk.  Thanks to those that helped me understand.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is an Array, but you're casting the result of `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` to an `NSDictionary`; cast it to an `NSArray` instead:

```
let jsonObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
```

**Note:** *You can also exclude the `AnyObject!` type declaration and just do:*

```
let jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
```

Comment: And to avoid this type of issue in the future, you can use optional casting (`as?` instead of `as`)

Comment: Thanks all.  Obvious once you told me.